# javascript auto form iterate and submit via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've a form with variable number of input fields, so the fields are not fixed.

I've looked jQuery ajax form submission but it involves manually building the queryString.

In this case number of input fields are unknown and it could be any.

Is there a javascript utility that iterates through input fields in a form and submit the form via ajax.

Need to have a callback as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `serialize` on the `form` object:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/my_url_target",
  data: $('#myform').serialize(),
  datatype: "json",
  traditional: true,
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
    // success
  },
  error: function() {
    // error
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method can serialize the fields on a form.

Here is an example of its usage:

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("/some/url", $(this).serialize(),function(){
        //callback goes here
    });
});
```